# Search through a string for any one of the items in an Array

Tags: php, arrays, search

Here's my search array:

```
$aExt = array('png','jpg','gif');
```

I want to search through the variable:

```
$sIcon
```

How can I search if the variable includes anything in this array using PHP?

It's like in inverted in_array:

`strstr($sIcon, $aExt)` <- Can second arg be an array?

Comment: Could you provide some examples?  Would "I'd like to give you a gift?" match?  Or no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach to iterate over the elements in the array and then use strpos to see if the key is in the content of the variable:

```
foreach($aExt as $key) {
  if(strpos($sIcon, $key) !== false) {
    echo sprintf("%s is in the variable", $key);
  }
}
```

Looking at the names of your variables I think you're trying to figure out the extension of a file name. You can easily find out the extension of a file using the following:

```
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

In your case:

```
$ext = pathinfo($sIcon, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(in_array($ext, $aExt)) {
  echo "Valid icon!";
}
```

Comment: +1 for recommending to grab the extension first, and then just use `in_array()`.

Comment: @dan Thanks for the ideas.  I passed the image path to the function instead of just the name, than handled it with file_exists. Works great.